how to install Citus extension for postgresql-17
How to install Citus extension for postgresql-17? I have been looking for it on many search portals.
My intention is to install Citus extension for Postgres-17 version, any help much appreciated.
I have Alloy DB cluster & VM Instance Ubuntu 24.04 Pro Server LTS on google cloud, works well with docker Postgres Citus.
By default Google on this Instance installs Postgresql-17, and I am not able to find the right equivalent Citus extension for this Postgres-17 version.
I have tried the following steps:
This is from Citus portal: It does not work since my instance has Postgres-17:
curl https://install.citusdata.com/community/deb.sh | sudo bash
sudo apt-get -y install postgresql-16-citus-12.1
sudo pg_conftool 16 main set shared_preload_libraries citus

This is from Citus GitHub, this does not work since it has Citus 12.1 extension for Postgres-16:
git clone https://github.com/citusdata/citus.git
cd citus
./configure
make
sudo make install

This works since its docker, but its not my most preferred option:
# run PostgreSQL with Citus on port 5500
docker run -d --name citus -p 5500:5432 -e POSTGRES_PASSWORD=mypassword citusdata/citus

# connect using psql within the Docker container
docker exec -it citus psql -U postgres

# or, connect using local psql
psql -U postgres -d postgres -h localhost -p 5500

